# How to extract the elements of a Haskell list which are on the even position

Tags: list, haskell

Hello dear Community,

I want to get all elements which are on a even position in a list. It's for the implementation of a Dart game.

e.g. `[((3,20),(1,19),(2,17)),((3,20),(2,12),(2,19))] -> [((3,20),(1,19),(2,17))]`

So far i have tried:

```
positioneven n [] = []
positioneven n (x:xs) = if even n
                          then (x: positioneven n+1 xs)
                          else     positioneven n+1 xs
```

But this of course didn't work. I would be very glad if someone can suggest me a better solution.

Thank you ! Nazar

Comment: You just need parens around `n+1`. As it is, it's parsed as `(positioneven n) + (1 xs)` which is clearly not what you intended.

Comment: Ouh yes ! Thank you, I got it.                                                                  position :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
position n [] = []
position n (x:xs) = if even n then x: (position (n+1) xs) else position (n+1) xs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two useful functions for the price of one:

```
evens (x:xs) = x:odds xs
evens _ = []

odds (_:xs) = evens xs
odds _ = []
```

Answer (score 5):

We can construct a function `even_elem :: [a] -> [a]` that has as basecase of course an empty list:

```
even_elem [] = []
```

furthermore if we pass it a list with one element, we return the list with that element:

```
even_elem [x] = [x]
```

finally in case we have a list with two elements or more `(x1:x2:t)`, we emit the first element `x1` and perform recursion on the tail `t`:

```
even_elem (x1:_:t) = x1 : even_elem t
```

or putting it together:

```
even_elem :: [a] -> [a]
even_elem [] = []
even_elem [x] = [x]
even_elem (x1:_:t) = x1 : even_elem t
```

We can simplify this, if we make the assumption that the definition of `[]` will never change, by reordering the patterns:

```
even_elem :: [a] -> [a]
even_elem (x1:_:t) = x1 : even_elem t
even_elem l = l
```

Comment: Hey Willem, Thank you !

Comment: You have a number of calls here to `evens`, which doesn't exist. Looks like you did a partial rename.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use a `foldr` with `zip` like;

```
evens :: [a] -> [a]    
evens = foldr (\t r -> if fst t `mod` 2 == 0 then snd t : r else r) [] . (zip [0..])
```

Comment: or a list comprehension `evens xs = [ x | (n,x) <- zip [0..] xs, even n ]`

Comment: or using a `cycle`: `evens = catMaybes . zipWith ($) (cycle [Just, const Nothing])`

Comment: or with `ZipList` type `evens = concat . getZipList . (ZipList (cycle [return, const []]) <*>) . ZipList`